# Getting Initial View Controller from Storyboard inside the App Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, uistoryboard

I am trying to access the initial viewcontroller of my storyboard. It is a navigation controller which is wired up to a second viewcontroller via a seque. So after my application did finish launching I want to directly show the viewController that is connected through the segue. I tried it out with code like this but it doesn't work ...

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
[navController.topViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLoginScreen" sender:self];
```

What am I doing wrong?

***4 years later***:

If I look at my question again after 4 years, I honestly have no idea what my real problem was.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Be sure you have tick marked the

> *is initial ViewController*

option for `UINavigationController` in storyBoard

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * myStoryBoardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that. And if i want to get the first view controller of my navigation controller ? myStoryBoardInitialViewController.topViewController ?

Comment: topViewController will give you the topMost viewController on the navigation stack..try this to fetch first viewcontroller..        [myStoryBoardInitialViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: When i am doing so i got the following error-message : **Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x9f6fee0> on <UINavigationController: 0xab40560> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!** :/

Comment: Code : `UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard~IPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController * myStoryboardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [[myStoryboardInitialViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLoginScreen" sender:self];`

Comment: make the bundle nil instead of the [[NSBundle mainBundle]]\

Comment: It seems to be that it has something to do with the seque beeing modal.. if i change it to push there is no error message mut it still doesnt work ..

Comment: are you trying to present the navigationController at the start up ??

Comment: I want to ask something that instantiateInitialViewController will be instantiating the initial view controller again or it will be returning the current instance which already exists?

Comment: It will initialize a new instance of view controller. If you want to get the existing view controller , you will have to refer the UINavigationController stack array's objectAtZeroth index.

Answer (score 4):

Sebastian, I'm not sure why you would want to start the initial view controller manually - all my projects (which all use storyboards) do this automatically if you ticked "Use Storyboards" on the second screen in the "New Project" wizard.

Maybe you need to mark the storyboard scene as inital? This can be done in the scene's attribute inspector by ticking the "Is Initial View Controller" - rather obviously named.

And then - if you really have a unusual setup which requires you to access the scenes manually, you can use the following:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName: "StoryboardName"
                                             bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
```

(Beware - no code completion here, so check spelling again.)

Or maybe I am getting your question completely wrong..? Happy hacking!

Comment: I am trying to implement the Facebook Connect. And if my app launches and a session isnt still available i want to show the login view which is connected to my initialview controller via a seque... maybe this screenshot helps you to understand my problem : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/bildschirmfoto20121108u.png/

Comment: Sebastian, seems like you want to display not the initial view controller, but the one connected via segue to the first. (Reading your initial question again, I could have guessed that...) In addition to the `instantiateInitialViewController` method, there is a `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method on the storyboard object. So you would have to name your second scene, and use that name to get access to it.

Comment: Hmm , it still doesnt work. I used the following code `UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard~IPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController * myStoryboardInitialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuViewController"];
    [myStoryboardInitialViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLoginScreen" sender:self];`.. inside the console i get this message _Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x9faac20> on <MenuViewController: 0x9fa9b50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!_

Comment: Sebastian, I don't know how you named the view controllers (their "identifiers"). Is "MenuViewController" the first or the second row? If it's the first, you can get it more easily with `instantiateInitialViewController`. If it's the second, as I suspect, you don't need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, just present it. Crossing a segue means to go from one scene to another, and as you don't have one on the screen yet, `performSegueWithIdentifier` is not what you want. Anyway, the segue leads from the first to the second, so I was expecting a different error in this case... hmm.

Comment: ... (continued) I guess you just need to say `[vc presentViewController]` instead of the `performSegue` method. I'm not sure, I never did that manually. Grüße von nobi

Answer (score 0):

In my app i have tabBar

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

TabBarController *tabBar = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];

_window.rootViewController = tabBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a reason in the year 2022 pre SwiftUI apps. Your apps starts... it has several choices, one, it wants you to login, two it wants you to sync with home base, and three everything is fine and just show the main UI. Case two may refresh a rather large body of information before you build out you main UI.