# iOS App Internal Control Transfer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a novice to iOS app development. While using the StoryBoards for creating the iOS app, the control transfers from `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` methods to the `viewDidLoad()` method directly without any code been mentioned in the `applicationDidFinishLauching()` method.

What is the internal process that occurs in this scenario.

I have seen in the main.m file that there is a piece of code which calls the AppDelegate.class, but nothing such is present in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default storyboard with initial controller (the arrow incoming to controller). this controller is initiated first after Application initialization is done. I mean, there is no explicit code for this, the Cocoa makes it for you.

Comment: Is it possible to view the code, which Cocoa makes ?

Comment: No, the implementation is hidden of course. It makes absolutely the same with what you do when instantiate ViewController manually from storyboard.

Comment: look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289158/getting-initial-view-controller-from-storyboard-inside-the-app-delegate)